# Embedding font and non-ISO-8859-1 characters in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, file-format

**Background**:

I am not able to install a 3rd party library as iText or anything similiar. I have to write a PDF package myself.

I am looking for a resource covering and explaining how to embedd fonts and texts in the PDF file format. So far, I have a pretty good coverage about adding rectangles, ISO-8859-1 texts and n-hedrons using `Path` elements.

Now, the next step is supporting UTF-8 charset (or overall just `different` charsets) with different fonts. Reading the ISO-32000:2008 I cannot understand how to that (the overall document is very techy and I am still a junior developer).

I found PDFBox, but I am having a hard time understanding the overcomplicated principles and decisions made.

If anyone has a reference to simple code examples or cookboks how to handle texts properly in the PDF file format, I appreciate if you link it.

***If the language matters***:

I am using Java. But I am more looking for a generous text/ article covering the topic with examples in any language.

Comment: A generic PDF package (like iText, PDFBox, etc) is way too much for a single junior developer. Forget it. If on the other hand you don't want to implement a generic package but merely a PDF creator with some limited functionality, you may have a chance. That been said, though, even then you should be able to work with ISO norms, and claiming "overcomplicated principles" in PDFBox does make you appear not up to even that limited task. (PDFBox is not very complicated, in particular as far as regular PDF generation is concerned.)

Comment: That been said, asking for external resources is off-topic on stack overflow, and an in-depth explanation of PDF font encoding is too broad for a stack overflow answer.

Comment: The PDF specification and the different fonts are complex, thus the software is complex. It has been created in 2002 and many people have worked on it and it's still not completed. Having non ISO-8859-1 characters in PDF is quite tricky, it was missing in PDFBox until the version 2.0, and there were some tricky bugs found over a year later. Definitively too much for a "junior developer in training" and also too much for a question here. Btw if you need to start from scratch then it's risky to look at existing code, because of "subconsciously" copying.

Comment: I wonder why you can't use PDFBox. The license is really "nice".

Comment: To add to what was said. PDF makes use of utf-8 for some things, but not in connection with fonts and glyphs.  The Fonts chapter of the PDF specification covers about 6 different font technologies.  But there is a bit of a documentation gap between the built-in Latin-1 (WinAnsi and MacRoman) character sets and the east Asian language support.  In that gap lies Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew, and Arabic, among other languages.  It's not a trivial task. Not insurmountable if you want to dedicate your life to it, but you would only be redoing the work of others who have actually already done just that.